# I've finished 100 days of consecutive login's into SF and I should have been getting the Fanatic badge but it's not there, how could this be?

Tags: support, badges

Today is my 100th consecutive day in visiting the site and when I looked on my profile it said something like "Thanks for your efforts, you've earned the Fanatic badge, let's track the next badge..." but when I look in my badges the Fanatic one is missing, why is that?

Comment: If you solve your question yourself, it would be nice if you write an answer instead of just deleting it.

Comment: @sven, you see the 3 downvotes? That's what I wanted to avoid when I deleted my question.

Comment: Meta up/downvotes don't affect reputation, they're only used as a method for agreement or disagreement.

Comment: @Hyppy: Exactly. And your answer has two upvotes.

Comment: @Hyppy Despite that downs have a significant psychological pressure, even on meta.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Okay, It seems like there was a delay until I pressed the Reputation updates button on the top panel and only then I received the badge.

Comment: You can (should) accept your own answer, too.

Comment: 15 more hours until i can.

Comment: Yeah, I've been tricked by the delay, too.  :)

Comment: I think that achievement and the Vox Populi get picked up in a daily `cron` job that runs after midnight UTC.